# nodejs array filtering - filter, include, or what?r?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, javascript-objects

I have array of two or more objects (*var_dump() attached).
I am trying to lookup for array with 'Type=A'. In this case it's [0], but sometimes its 5 and etc.. I was trying to do it with .includes and .filter, but no luck.

my coude output:

```
object(2) {
    ["host"] => array(2) {
        [0] => object(1) {
            ["$"] => object(10) {
                ["HostId"] => string(9) "326540292"
                ["Name"] => string(1) "@"
                ["Type"] => string(1) "A"
                ["Address"] => string(14) "1.1.1.1"
                ["MXPref"] => string(2) "10"
                ["TTL"] => string(2) "60"
                ["AssociatedAppTitle"] => string(0) ""
                ["FriendlyName"] => string(0) ""
                ["IsActive"] => string(4) "true"
                ["IsDDNSEnabled"] => string(5) "false"
            }
        }
        [1] => object(1) {
            ["$"] => object(10) {
                ["HostId"] => string(9) "326540291"
                ["Name"] => string(3) "www"
                ["Type"] => string(5) "CNAME"
                ["Address"] => string(19) "domain.com."
                ["MXPref"] => string(2) "10"
                ["TTL"] => string(3) "300"
                ["AssociatedAppTitle"] => string(0) ""
                ["FriendlyName"] => string(0) ""
                ["IsActive"] => string(4) "true"
                ["IsDDNSEnabled"] => string(5) "false"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I am trying to get IP of record Type 'A'

any easy way to do it on NodeJS ?

This is code:

```
var namecheapApi = require('namecheap-api') 
const var_dump = require('var_dump')

....

namecheapApi.apiCall("namecheap.domains.dns.getHosts", {'SLD':sld,'TLD':tld}).then(function (data)
          {
         
           var test =  data['response'][0]["DomainDNSGetHostsResult"][0]["host"].filter(function(itemas) {
             return itemas.match(/\d+/).Type=="A";
           });

           var_dump (test);

  }
      );
  }
  
}
```

Comment: `var_dump` is a PHP function, and the output you've provided looks like PHP output. You've said "I was trying to do it with .includes and .filter, but no luck.", but you haven't shown your attempt so its hard to tell what the problem is. Try providing a [mcve].

Comment: Show the JSON output and your javascript code.

Comment: This is NodeJS, not PHP, I am using var_dump library for nice output :) I have provided more information, sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

E.g. *(assuming the data is indeed javascript, i.e. the "[var_dump](https://www.npmjs.com/package/var_dump)" output, and not PHP code)* change your example like this:

```
return itemas['$'].Type === "A";
```

*(I can't imagine where the `.match(/\d+/)` came from, which is either just wrong code, or suggests there is some other, not mentioned library involved)*